# animate width of div when scrolling

Tags: jquery-animate, width

First of all, I'm new to jquery and I'm not very good at it. I have a div with a fixed width and I want it to expand to full width when you start scrolling down. So far I have the code below:

```
var fullwidth = $(window).width();
var smallwidth = 1100;

$(window).scroll(function(){    
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#navigation').animate({width: fullwidth}, 1000);
    } else {
        $('#navigation').animate({width: smallwidth}, 1000);
    }
});
```

What this does is that it will expand when you scroll, but it wont shrink back when you're scrolling all the way top again. When I use fadeOut and fadeIn it works perfectly. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Gr, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

$(window).scroll() does't run "real time" but in fact it's triggered every couple ms or more. 
I'd suggest you have a look at [throttle/debounce jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/throttle/)

I did a little mockup, on jsfiddle, you can find it here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nosxn7cm/1/)

The code is pretty self-explanatory I think.
Basically, debounce plugin runs the callback function every 250ms, even if the last window scroll trigger was called in less than 250ms ago.

JS:

```
var fullwidth = $(window).width();
var smallwidth = 1100;

$(window).scroll( $.throttle( 250, animate ) )

function animate() {
    var navi = $('#navigation');
    //we're adding .wide class to avoid multiple runs of this animation.
    if (window.pageYOffset > 0 && !navi.hasClass('wide')) {
        navi.addClass("wide").stop().animate({width: fullwidth}, 1000);
    }

    if (window.pageYOffset == 0 ) {
        console.clear();
        console.log(smallwidth);
        navi.stop().animate({width: smallwidth}, 1000, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('wide');
        });
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your awnser, I got it working now! I still don't fully understand why my code wasn't working. It did work with fadeIn / fadeOut but not with animate, that seems a bit odd.

One more thing, is there an solution without using that throttle/debounce jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Also, I kinda got it working add .stop() before the .animate(). However what that does is that when you scroll the animation stutters during every scroll action. I made an example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/et8hghuw/

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  var fullwidth = $(window).width();
  if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
    var smallwidth = 500;
  } else {
    var smallwidth = $(window).width();
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('#navigation').css('width', fullwidth);
  } else {
    $('#navigation').css('width', smallwidth);
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fullwidth = $(window).width();
  if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
    var smallwidth = 500;
  } else {
    var smallwidth = $(window).width();
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('#navigation').stop().animate({
      width: fullwidth
    }, 200);
  } else {
    $('#navigation').stop().animate({
      width: smallwidth
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

Any way of getting rid of that stuttering?